# Quarterly year-to-year changes

Tags: r, function, dataframe, loops

I have a quarterly time series. I am trying to apply a function which is supposed calculate the year-to-year growth and year-to-year difference and multiply a variable by (-1).

I already used a similar function for calculating quarter-to-quarter changes and it worked.
I modified this function for yoy changes and it does not have any effect on my data frame. And any error popped up.

Do you have any suggestion how to modify the function or how to accomplish to apply the yoy change function on a time series?

Here is the code:

```
Date <- c("2004-01-01","2004-04-01", "2004-07-01","2004-10-01","2005-01-01","2005-04-01","2005-07-01","2005-10-01","2006-01-01","2006-04-01","2006-07-01","2006-10-01","2007-01-01","2007-04-01","2007-07-01","2007-10-01")
B1 <- c(3189.30,3482.05,3792.03,4128.66,4443.62,4876.54,5393.01,5885.01,6360.00,6930.00,7430.00,7901.00,8279.00,8867.00,9439.00,10101.00)
B2 <- c(7939.97,7950.58,7834.06,7746.23,7760.59,8209.00,8583.05,8930.74,9424.00,9992.00,10041.00,10900.00,11149.00,12022.00,12662.00,13470.00)
B3 <- as.numeric(c("","","","",140.20,140.30,147.30,151.20,159.60,165.60,173.20,177.30,185.30,199.30,217.10,234.90))
B4 <- as.numeric(c("","","","",-3.50,-14.60,-11.60,-10.20,-3.10,-16.00,-4.90,-17.60,-5.30,-10.90,-12.80,-8.40))
df <- data.frame(Date,B1,B2,B3,B4)
```

The code will produce following data frame:

```
Date       B1       B2    B3    B4
1  2004-01-01  3189.30  7939.97    NA    NA
2  2004-04-01  3482.05  7950.58    NA    NA
3  2004-07-01  3792.03  7834.06    NA    NA
4  2004-10-01  4128.66  7746.23    NA    NA
5  2005-01-01  4443.62  7760.59 140.2  -3.5
6  2005-04-01  4876.54  8209.00 140.3 -14.6
7  2005-07-01  5393.01  8583.05 147.3 -11.6
8  2005-10-01  5885.01  8930.74 151.2 -10.2
9  2006-01-01  6360.00  9424.00 159.6  -3.1
10 2006-04-01  6930.00  9992.00 165.6 -16.0
11 2006-07-01  7430.00 10041.00 173.2  -4.9
12 2006-10-01  7901.00 10900.00 177.3 -17.6
13 2007-01-01  8279.00 11149.00 185.3  -5.3
14 2007-04-01  8867.00 12022.00 199.3 -10.9
15 2007-07-01  9439.00 12662.00 217.1 -12.8
16 2007-10-01 10101.00 13470.00 234.9  -8.4
```

And I want to apply following changes on the variables:

```
# yoy absolute difference change 
abs.diff = c("B1","B2")
# yoy percentage change
percent.change = c("B3")
# make the variable negative
negative = c("B4")
```

This is the fuction that I am trying to use for my data frame.

```
transformation = function(D,abs.diff,percent.change,negative) 
{  
  TT <- dim(D)[1]
  DData <- D[-1,]
  nms <- c()
  for (i in c(2:dim(D)[2])) { 
    # yoy absolute difference change
    if (names(D)[i] %in% abs.diff) 
    {    DData[,i] = (D[5:TT,i]-D[1:(TT-4),i])
    names(DData)[i] = paste('a',names(D)[i],sep='') }   
    
    # yoy  percent. change
    if (names(D)[i] %in% percent.change) 
    { DData[,i] = 100*(D[5:TT,i]-D[1:(TT-4),i])/D[1:(TT-4),i]
    names(DData)[i] = paste('p',names(D)[i],sep='') }
    
    #CA.deficit
    if (names(D)[i] %in% negative) 
    { DData[,i] = (-1)*D[1:TT,i] }
    
  }
  return(DData)  
}
```

This is what I would like to get :

```
      Date   pB1   pB2  aB3   B4
1  2004-01-01    NA    NA   NA   NA
2  2004-04-01    NA    NA   NA   NA
3  2004-07-01    NA    NA   NA   NA
4  2004-10-01    NA    NA   NA   NA
5  2005-01-01 39.33 -2.26   NA  3.5
6  2005-04-01 40.05  3.25   NA 14.6
7  2005-07-01 42.22  9.56   NA 11.6
8  2005-10-01 42.54 15.29 11.0 10.2
9  2006-01-01 43.13 21.43 19.3  3.1
10 2006-04-01 42.11 21.72 18.3 16.0
11 2006-07-01 37.77 16.99 22.0  4.9
12 2006-10-01 34.26 22.05 17.7 17.6
13 2007-01-01 30.17  18.3 19.7  5.3
14 2007-04-01 27.95 20.32 26.1 10.9
15 2007-07-01 27.04  26.1 39.8 12.8
16 2007-10-01 27.84 23.58 49.6  8.4
```

Comment: Could you show how would `df` look after transformation, i.e. your expected output?

Comment: Could you edit your question with the actual mathematical calculation that you expect to make? And, as jay.sf wrote, and example of the output you expect.

Comment: Sure, I added my expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping by the months, i.e. 6th and 7th `substr`ing using `ave` and do the necessary calculations. With `sapply` we may loop over the columns.

```
f <- function(x) {
  g <- substr(Date, 6, 7)
  l <- length(unique(g))
  o <- ave(x, g, FUN=function(x) 100/x * c(x[-1], NA) - 100)
  c(rep(NA, l), head(o, -4))
}

cbind(df[1], sapply(df[-1], f))
#          Date       B1        B2       B3         B4
# 1  2004-01-01       NA        NA       NA         NA
# 2  2004-04-01       NA        NA       NA         NA
# 3  2004-07-01       NA        NA       NA         NA
# 4  2004-10-01       NA        NA       NA         NA
# 5  2005-01-01 39.32901 -2.259202       NA         NA
# 6  2005-04-01 40.04796  3.250329       NA         NA
# 7  2005-07-01 42.21960  9.560688       NA         NA
# 8  2005-10-01 42.54044 15.291439       NA         NA
# 9  2006-01-01 43.12655 21.434066 13.83738 -11.428571
# 10 2006-04-01 42.10895 21.720063 18.03279   9.589041
# 11 2006-07-01 37.77093 16.986386 17.58316 -57.758621
# 12 2006-10-01 34.25636 22.050356 17.26190  72.549020
# 13 2007-01-01 30.17296 18.304329 16.10276  70.967742
# 14 2007-04-01 27.95094 20.316253 20.35024 -31.875000
# 15 2007-07-01 27.03903 26.102978 25.34642 161.224490
# 16 2007-10-01 27.84458 23.577982 32.48731 -52.272727
```